# View another webview webpage when pressing Settings (or other buttons)

Tags: android, webview

I'm building my first (android) app, and I am basing it on webview, as I am much stronger in PHP. I have created the page, and the app/webpage is working great. But to get things to work, I have created my own buttons on the webpage (for instance, about the app). But this would be better to use the menu function in Android Studio. F.ex. adding: `<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"` I now have the button, but I don't know how to link it to the about page.

Update 1:
Source code of WebviewActivity.java:

```
package com.***.***;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String HTTP_URL = "***index***";

    private static final String HTTP_URL_GRAPH = "***index***";

    private static final String TAG = WebviewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private WebView webView;

    static Dialog mDialog;

    private static final int ACTIVATE = 0;

    private static final long ACTIVATE_DELAY = 400;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting WebActivity ...");

        assignViews();
        assignCallbacks();
        createWebView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_graph) {
            createWebViewGraph();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // handler for activation of WebView (kind of loading)
    private static Handler webviewActivatorHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case ACTIVATE:
                    if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                    }
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void createWebView() {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // loading dialog
        mDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Light);
        mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.webview_overlay);
        mDialog.show();

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = ACTIVATE;
                webviewActivatorHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, ACTIVATE_DELAY);
                updateUI();
            }

        });

        if (DeviceHelper.isOnline(this)) {
            webView.loadUrl(HTTP_URL);
        } else {
            DialogHelper.displayCustomDialog(this, getString(R.string.offline),
                    getString(R.string.offline_msg));
            try {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error dismissing dialog");
            }
        }
    }

    private void createWebViewGraph() {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // loading dialog
        mDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Light);
        mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.webview_overlay);
        mDialog.show();

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.what = ACTIVATE;
                webviewActivatorHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, ACTIVATE_DELAY);
                updateUI();
            }

        });

        if (DeviceHelper.isOnline(this)) {
            webView.loadUrl(HTTP_URL_GRAPH);
        } else {
            DialogHelper.displayCustomDialog(this, getString(R.string.offline),
                    getString(R.string.offline_msg));
            try {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error dismissing dialog");
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        // update UI elements here
    }

    private void assignCallbacks() {
        // assign callbacks here
    }

    private void assignViews() {
        // assign views here
    }

}
```

Comment: You load the abour/settings page in your WebView in the same way as your main page. So i do not understand the problem.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to create another webview class, or is there an easier way?

Comment: I do not understand the problem, so how can i advice?

Comment: My problem is that I do not know how to do it. I am new to both app making and Java. And I am very unsure of how to go forward with this.

Comment: 'that I do not know how to do it.'. What is 'it'? Because as said before: there is no difference in loading an about or settings page in a webview as loading your first page. So please explain better which problem you have exactly.

Comment: Ok. So I will now post my source code. I tried copy the information about webview, and change the class name, so I can bring up just that. But it just loads my index page. The source code will be in the original post.

Comment: 'I tried copy the information about webview'. Which information? 'and change the class name' Which class? What was the class name? What is the class name now? Can you please be clear about where you are talking about and what you did? You also talk about 'action_settings' but that is not in your code. You talk about an 'about page' but i see no about page in your code.  'The source code will be in the original post.'???? Where are you talking about?

Comment: I have not created settings and about. Because I can't get the graph page to work.
private void createWebViewGraph() is the graph webview
and private void createWebView() is the regular.
the graph is collected at: public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {